# Magnetic Reissner-Nordstrom Black holes

Tags: electromagnetism, general-relativity, black-holes, magnetic-monopoles, reissner-nordstrom-metric

I am studying the RN black hole from Carroll, but i have a hard time following his explanations given in page 254.

To solve for the purely electrically charged black hole, one introduces the four-potential

$$A_{\mu} = (\mathcal{A}(r),0,0,0)~,$$
where $\mathcal{A}(r)$ is a radially depended scalar potential. This will give rise to an electric field of the form

$$\mathcal{E}(r) \hat{r} = - \partial_{r} \mathcal{A}(r) \hat{r}~,$$

so this gives rise to radially depended radial electric field. One can intepret this as a point particle sitting at the singularity of the black hole $r=0$.

Now, lets say that we want to introduce a radial magnetic field. In this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0005016) (equation 5) they mention that to discuss magnetic fields, besides electric ones, one introduces a modified gauge potential

$$A_{\mu} = (\mathcal{A}(r),0,0,Q_m \cos \theta)~.$$

My problem is that i cannot understand this particular choice for the gauge potential. How can we see explicitly from this gauge potential that the afforementioned choice will yield radial magnetic fields? Moreover, how is the radially magnetic field sourced? Is is sourced by a magnetic monopole located at the singularity $r=0$ as in the electrically charged case? Note that the resulting gauge potential one can obtain from Carroll is the same as this (page 255).

I have checked this gauge satisfies the Maxwell equation

$$\nabla_{\mu}F^{\mu\nu}=0~.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/609053/120730) it is mathematically possible to construct a so-called *dyonic* black hole carrying both electric $Q_e$ and magnetic $Q_m$ charge. For a non-rotating dyonic Reissner-Nordstrom black hole with both electric and magnetic charge is discussed in this article: [Dyonic Reissner-Nordstrom Black Holes and Superradiant Stability](https://arxiv.org/abs/2105.14702) in which they give
$$A_\nu=(-Q_e/r,0,0,Q_m(\cos\theta\mp1)) \tag{1}$$
in equation (2.6), *'where the upper minus sign applies to the north half-sphere of the black hole and the lower plus sign applies to the south half-sphere'*. The textbook expressions for the electric and magnetic field, see, e.g., [ROTATING NEUTRON STAR MODELS WITH MAGNETIC FIELD](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9503044v1), are
$$
\begin{align}
E^{(n)}_\alpha&=F_{\alpha\beta}n^\beta,\tag{2.1}\\
B^{(n)}_\alpha&=-\frac{1}{2}\epsilon_{\alpha\beta\mu\nu}n^\beta F^{\mu\nu},\tag{2.2}
\end{align}
$$
measured in the reference frame of an observer moving with the time-like velocity $n$. Plugging in the expressions for the dyonic Reissner-Nordstrom black hole one could work those fields out in detail (see Eqs. (4) and (5) of the [aforementioned reference](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9503044v1)) but in short one only gets electric and magnetic fields in radial direction. In that sense I suppose $Q_m$ would really be a magnetic monopole charge I suppose. Wether or not this is a 'physical' scenario at the singularity (also in relation to the no-hair theorem) I do not know.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you clarify what is the form of $n^\beta$? Will it be $(1,0,0,0)$ because this is a timelike velocity? In that case according to the second referenced paper we will have that $B_r = -\epsilon_{rt\theta\phi}n^tF^{\theta\phi}/2$ which indeed yields a radial magnetic field. However i still cannot grasp this choice with $A_{\phi} \sim \cos \theta$. Why can't this depend also on $r$? Anyway, thank you for your attempt!!!! +1

Comment: For a non-rotating configuration $n^\alpha=1/N(1,0,0,0)$ where $N$ is the so called lapse function i.e. $N=\sqrt{-g_{tt}}$. If you want to know more about this observer choice I would recommend reading up on the 3+1 formalism in numerical GR. If one were to allow a more general $A_\phi(r,\theta)$ one would get components $B_\theta\neq 0$. See again the equations (5) and (6) mentioned in the answer. Such fields would correspond to higher order multiple moments (beyond the monopole discussed here). In the Kerr-Newman metric one would get a dipole filed induced by the rotating electric one.